# Register addressing

Tags: assembly, x86

I have an exam tomorrow in this and I'm getting really confused about this question.What are the values contained in the AL and AH register after each instruction is executed. Assume AL=9 and AH=0 before each instruction is executed.

• nop (no operation they remain the same)

• mov al,ah (al=0 ah=0)

• push ax (pushs ah and al onto a stack?)

• dec  ax

• add ax,257

• add al,251

• shl al,2

I know the first few I get confused when the ax is mentioned, i.e,  add ax,257 should I add 257 onto ah and al? just remember al and ah are set back to 9 and 0 at the start of each instruction

Comment: So you have 0009 in AX, dec ax turns that into 8, adding 257 aka 0101 gives 010A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AX is the concatenation of AH and AL (or, in reverse, AL is the low byte of AX, and AH is the high byte of AX). So, before each instruction, AX=0009h.

When one of your instructions operates on AL, however, it won't affect AH at all.

Comment: Yeah, but how does adding into ax affect ah and al?

Comment: You'll get a new value in AX, the low byte of which will be in AL and the high byte of which will be in AH.

Comment: so say ah = 0 and al =10 and I want to add 256 onto ax. Would al = 245 and ah= 11

Comment: @user1244808: It's a lot easier to think of the splitting in hexadecimal. 10+256=266. 266 decimal = 010A hex. That means AH = 01 hex, and AL = 0A hex. Converting those back to decimal, we get 1 and 10 respectively.

Comment: I dont get this at all, sorry, bringing hex into it just confuses me more

Comment: @user1244808: That's what you really need to work on then. Trying to deal with assembly language on an 8086 without understanding hex is like trying to go swimming without getting wet.

Comment: I understand hex, I didn't think I needed it for this though, lecturer didnt cover this very well

Comment: Technically you don't need it -- it's just the easier way to do it. Without hex, you'd take 266/256 = 1 to get AH, and 266 % 256 = 10 to get AL.

Comment: I think I have it so say al was 7 and i want to add 266 onto ax that would be 7+266=273, in hex thats 0111. so al=01 and ah 11? please say thats right :L

Comment: No -- AL is the *low* byte, so AL=11, AH=01.

Comment: oh yeah sorry I get it, just one more question if you're adding 272  onto al itself do you do the same thing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. 272 >256, so it won't fit in one byte. Since AL is only one byte, you can only add one byte to it.

Comment: well just in one of the questions he says al is 9 and add 251 to it that would 260 which is too big as well :/

Comment: Yes, but the inputs are both within bounds. In that case, the result will be the low-byte of what the result "should have been", and the carry flag set to indicate the higher bit of the result.

Comment: so then in that case al would be 04?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that al and ah are just ways of referring to the lower and higher bytes of the ax register. With AX, its best to think about it as a 16 bit register when it appears, and then break it down into its lower and higher halves, when asked what the value of AH or AL is. So your register looks like this, if they start at 9 and 0:

```
 00000000   00001001
|________| |________|
    AH         AL
|___________________|
          AX
```

So, for instance `add ax, 257` looks like this:

```
    |0000000|  |00001001|
+
    |0000001|  |00000001|

=   |0000001|  |00001010|
```